# Show datas from tables that can have a same data in a column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I crawled some datas from a web then directly save them in database, so I got `$title`, `$url`, and `$author`. But, the number of `$author` for one `title` can more than 1 data. So, I separated `$author` from `$title` and `$url`. all `id` is auto increment.

```
tb_wrapper            tb_author
=================     ==================
|id| title | url|    |id|author|$title|
=================     ==================
|1 |titleA |urlA|    | 1| A    |titleA|
=================     | 2| B   |titleA|
                    ===================
```

in the other process(from document files that I got that their filename is same with $title), i have a table also that contain `$title` : `tb_doc`

```
======================
|id | content | title|
======================
|1  | contentA|titleA|
======================
```

I need to get datas from those 3 tables, so I can get the result like :
`titleA has URLA contentA and author  A and B`

here's the code :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT
                            tb_wrapper.url,
                            tb_wrapper.title,
                            tb_author.title,
                            tb_author.author,
                            tb_doc.content,
                            tb_doc.title
                       FROM
                            tb_doc
                       INNER JOIN tb_wrapper ON tb_doc.title = tb_wrapper.title
                       INNER JOIN tb_author ON tb_wrapper.title = tb_author.title ");
```

But, from that,  I got duplicate result, author A and B are separated. please, help me, what join I have to do ? thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like so:

```
SELECT w.url, w.title, a.title, a.authors, 
  d.content, d.title
FROM tb_doc d
INNER JOIN tb_wrapper w  ON d.title = w.title
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(author SEPARATOR ', ') AS authors
   FROM  tb_author
   GROUP BY title
 ) a ON w.title = a.title
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f622d/1)